# Java, How to read binary data to any file type

Tags: java, file, binary

I would like to know if its possible to read binary data from a blobstore and convert it into the desired file type. eg.

I receive binary data representing these files

```
example.txt
example.jpg
example.pdf
```

Would I have to parse the files names from the string name and to get the file type, then use those types to encode the binary back to the desired file type?

Comment: What exactly do you want as your output?

Comment: In theory it's possible. I don't know of any library which does this though.

Comment: @Nulano I would want the correctly encoded files as the output? Not just an array of byte data

Comment: Binary files (such as pdf, zip, jpg) are encoded as an array of bytes. Just write them to the disk with a `FileOutputStream`. Text files are usually encoded with the system-default encoding. You can try `new String(data)`, or wrap your `InputStream` (or `ByteArrayInputStream`) into a `Reader`. (or you can just write the data as bytes and let the system handle it)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the data exactly as you got it using the name.  No conversion needed.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Its an array of byte data.

Comment: The files are already in the correct format (the byte array contains bytes representing the JPG format or TXT format).  Just because you stored a JPG does not mean that somekind of conversion is happening, it just stored the bytes.  Reading them again is therefore just a matter of writing those bytes back to a file.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now that I think about it., Thanks